# jQuery error clicking on element with 2 click handlers

Tags: jquery

I have 2 click handlers for the same element.

Say #1

```
$(':input, a').bind('click', function(e) {  
  if(e.ctrlKey) {
     // do something with all links and inputs
  }
});
```

and #2:

```
$('a#some-special-link').click(function() {
 // do something special also with current link only
});
```

When I click the first time on the link *"a#some-special-link"* I always get an error inside jQuery core line:
***return typeof jQuery !== "undefined" && !jQuery.event.triggered ?***

```
if ( !eventHandle ) {
    elemData.handle = eventHandle = function() {
        // Handle the second event of a trigger and when
        // an event is called after a page has unloaded
        return typeof jQuery !== "undefined" && !jQuery.event.triggered ?
            jQuery.event.handle.apply( eventHandle.elem, arguments ) :
            undefined;
    };
}
```

The error says:
*TypeError: Type error on line:2200 Source:http://localhost/js/jquery-1.5.1.js*

The error happens only the first time I click on the a#some-special-link link. The every next time both click handlers work fine.

I'm not sure what is the reason. What I need is both #1 and #2 click handlers executed.

Please, help me to find what is going on there...

***Update:*** I get the same error (when I change the event to hover, and hover mouse to any link or input):

```
$(':input, a').bind('hover', function(e) ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you shorten the binding of the second click handler to an onclick="someFunction();"?  since it is an ID that you are searching for to bind in the first place there should only be 1 element that is returned with that second selector?  so your code would look something like:

```
$(':input, a').bind('click', function(e) {  
  if(e.ctrlKey) {
     // do something with all links and inputs
  }
});
```

...

```
<a id="some-special-link" onclick="someFunction();"></a>
```

HTH

Comment: I can edit the #1 click handler only, I can't change neither #2 click handler nor "some-special-link" tag definition